# Where should I put this question?

Tags: discussion, policy, asking-questions

I submitted this question: [Difference between dynamic system and complex system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575348/difference-between-dynamic-system-and-complex-system)

And it was noted to me that this didn't belong to the site, so the first thing I ask is: why? and the second is: Where should I put it?

I really don't want to mess up the dinamic of the site, so this kind of worries me.

Comment: I don't find anything inappropriate about your question.  It's a little "soft", but not past the range of acceptability.

Comment: I agree with @PeteL.Clark, it is soft, but interesting. A nice thing about it taking 5 votes from experienced users to close/reopen a question is that your question doesn't get shut down from the opinion of just one user.

Comment: @WillieWong phewwww... that is nice. But maybe I can improve my question so it's not as soft like Pete said, what can I do?

Comment: This is a perfectly acceptable question for MSE, especially with the [tag:soft-question] qualifier.  The commenter is expressing his personal opinion, which is not shared universally.

Comment: @AnaGalois: unfortunately, if I know how to make the question less soft, I would probably also know how to give you a precise answer.